# Trying to initialize 2 values in 2 variables using 1 query, is it possible to do this.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SET @Password = (
    SELECT UserPassword,IsLocked 
    FROM [Authentication].[tblLogin] 
    WHERE UserName=@UserName)
```

i m trying to get both values userpassword and islocked in two variables to be used in same SP in next query. Is it possible or do i have to write two queries for this.
Is it there a concept of arrays in sql server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `select` instead of `set`:

```
select 
    @Password = Password
,   @IsLocked = IsLocked
,   @UserLongName = UserLongName
,   @TopSecretPin = 1234
,   @PrefersLinux = case when LastName = 'Torvalds' then 1 else 0 end
FROM [Authentication].[tblLogin] 
WHERE UserName = @UserName
```